# Module as a singleton in Python

Tags: python, singleton

There are quite a few posts on the web where ppl seem to propose using a module as a singleton in Python. Could you please help me understand how to do that? Apparently I am doing it wrong. I writing an application and I want to keep "shared state" as a singleton. This a very basic example of what I am doing

```
singleton.py
    state = []
```

and on another file:

```
a.py
    import singleton
    singleton.state.append("a")
    print(singleton.state)
```

and the `print` command in `a.py` outputs `['a']` which is what we expect. Then if there is a module `b.py` that looks like

```
b.py
    import singleton
    singleton.state.append("b")
    print(singleton.state)
```

the `print` command will give `['b']` which is expected but not what I was hoping for if I had a singleton. I was hoping for something like `[a,b]`. Ofcourse any other ideas on best practices to keep shared information are highly welcome

Comment: Are you hoping that `singleton.state` would persist from one Python session to the next? It won't. `a` and `b` will share `singleton.state` only if they are both imported in the same python process.

Comment: can you be more specific about why you are trying to share this information?  It's often sufficient to have a state object that exists in the executing file (sometimes using `if __name__ == '__main__':`)